# C strtok, what if I want to keep the delimiter?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm trying to split lines of the type:

```
GM 1 2 3 ! this is a comment
```

to separate out the comment section. There are several possible comment delimiters, !, ' and #. `strtok` is the obvious solution for this:

```
card->card_str = strtok(line_buf, "!'#");
```

producing `GM 1 2 3` and `this is a comment`. However, for this role, I need to keep the delimiter character in the second string, so in this case `! this is a comment`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `strtok` is just a quick and dirty way of doing it, emphasis on dirty. If you want to write your own tokenizer you can always do that with a simple loop.

Comment: "Is there an easy way to do this?" Yes, but post more code to show the context how `card->card_str` is used.

Comment: Use `strpbrk()` instead of `strtok()`. That's all. But note that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101200/c-strtok-what-if-i-want-to-keep-the-delimiter#comment85207689_49101200) is really important to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtok` is rarely the right tool for parsing jobs because it has many quirks and side effects.

For your goal, you can use `strcspn()`:

```
void parse_input_line(const char *line) {
    size_t len = strcspn(line, "!'#");
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, line, len);
        p[len] = '\0';
        card->card_str = p;
        card->card_comment = p[len] ? strdup(p + len) : NULL;
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can use `strpbrk`:

```
void parse_input_line(const char *line) {
    const char *sep = strpbrk(line, "!'#");
    if (sep == NULL) {
        // no comment
        card->card_str = strdup(line);
        card->card_comment = NULL;
    } else {
        size_t len = sep - line;
        char *p = malloc(len + 1);
        if (p != NULL) {
            memcpy(p, line, len);
            p[len] = '\0';
            card->card_str = p;
            card->card_comment = strdup(sep);
        }
    }   
}
```

You can use `strndup` to make the code more readable:

```
void parse_input_line(const char *line) {
    size_t len = strcspn(line, "!'#");
    if (p[len] == '\0') {
        /* no comment */
        card->card_str = strdup(line);
        card->card_comment = NULL;
    } else {
        card->card_str = strndup(line, len);
        card->card_comment = strdup(p + len);
    }
}
```

`strndup` may not be available on all systems, here is a simple implementation:

```
size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t n) {
    size_t len;
    for (len = 0; len < n; len++) {
        if (s[len] == '\0')
            break;
    }
    return len;
}

char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    size_t len = strnlen(s, n);
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, len);
        p[len] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Or `strpbrk()` which is more like `strtok()`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: `strpbrk` can be used too, as shown.

Comment: This looks good, but I see two copies in the second case... don't I need *either* the dup or the memcpy?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: `malloc` + `memcpy` could be replaced with a call to `strndup` if this function is available on your system. If not, it is easy to write and would make the code clearer.